# Get elements from array untill a condition matches

Tags: javascript, loops, search, dictionary

I have an array like this

```
var arr = [
    "/a_3312368_392921_800MHz", 
    "/a_3312368_392853_900MHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578261_1GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578167_140GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578230_160GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578192_180GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_397393_183GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_582870_186GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578174_190GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578177_2GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578922_210GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578479_220GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578357_226GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578182_240GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578919_250GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578349_253GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578639_280GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_579178_3GHz"
];
```

I need to get value on an operator selection. I have some operators like this

```
`> , < , = , <= , >=`
```

And here is the selected value for example

```
var selection = "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz";
```

My current operator for instance

```
var operator = ">";
```

This is some code i have written.

```
var string_array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(selection == arr[i]){
        break;
    }
    string_array.push(arr[i]);
}
console.log(string_array);
```

It is giving me proper results. But when i am trying it with map it produces error `Can't have break outside of loop`.

```
string_array = arr.map(function(item) {  if (selection == item){ break; }  else {return item;} });
```

How can i write a one line code for this.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dj9okt7q/1/)

Comment: Use [*Array.prototype.some*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some) or [*.every*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.every) which iterate until the condition returns true or false.

Comment: @RobG but they don't construct an array "automatically"...

Comment: ***One liner*** shouldn't be your design goal. Readable, maintainable code should be. As a secondary goal, performance (breaking early is crucial with large data. `for(...) { ...}` outperforms array iteration functions)

Comment: @RobG requirement is ***One liner***. `some`/`every` won't fit the bill here.

Comment: `map` return array with same element count, you need _filter_, or _reduce_

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of your code? you're not using the `operator` variable, what is it for?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I _think_ it's an attempt to take all members of a sorted array up to and including the `selection`.

Comment: @RichChurcher that's what the code *does*, but the unused `operator` makes me think the code does not represent the intent.

Comment: @Touffy I wondered if perhaps the intent was to take elements greater than, elements less than, etc. But it's all a lottery :)

Comment: as i told i have different operator for which i using switch case for `<` and `>` and so on. i don't want to write loops inside every case

Comment: So in the case of operator '>' you want to get all the array items up (and not including) to the first one that's equal to `selection`? That makes no sense unless your starting array is sorted.

Comment: well i will write a different condition for this of course

Comment: Then please explain your intent, because we can't help if we keep guessing wrong.

Comment: @raheelshan, are you sure that your array have right order? seems like it sorted wrong: 3Ghz should be less then 280GHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well… you can't break map. Don't use `map`. Use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

**Example - some:** -  `some` will break when the callback returns `true`

```
arr.some(function (item) {if (selection == item) {return true;}});
```

```js
var selection = "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz";
var arr = ["/a_3312368_392921_800MHz", "/a_3312368_392853_900MHz", "/a_3312368_578261_1GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz", "/a_3312368_578167_140GHz", "/a_3312368_578230_160GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578192_180GHz", "/a_3312368_397393_183GHz", "/a_3312368_582870_186GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578174_190GHz", "/a_3312368_578177_2GHz", "/a_3312368_578922_210GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578479_220GHz", "/a_3312368_578357_226GHz", "/a_3312368_578182_240GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578919_250GHz", "/a_3312368_578349_253GHz", "/a_3312368_578639_280GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_579178_3GHz"
];

string_array =  [];
arr.some(function(item) { if (selection == item){ return true; }else{string_array.push(item);}
});
console.log(string_array);
```

**Example-every:** - `every` will break when the callback returns `false`

```
arr.every(function(item) { if (selection == item) {return false;}});
```

```js
var selection = "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz";
var arr = ["/a_3312368_392921_800MHz", "/a_3312368_392853_900MHz", "/a_3312368_578261_1GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz", "/a_3312368_578167_140GHz", "/a_3312368_578230_160GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578192_180GHz", "/a_3312368_397393_183GHz", "/a_3312368_582870_186GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578174_190GHz", "/a_3312368_578177_2GHz", "/a_3312368_578922_210GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578479_220GHz", "/a_3312368_578357_226GHz", "/a_3312368_578182_240GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578919_250GHz", "/a_3312368_578349_253GHz", "/a_3312368_578639_280GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_579178_3GHz"
];

string_array = [];
arr.every(function(item) {if (selection != item){string_array.push(item);} return item.indexOf(selection) == -1;
});

console.log(string_array);
```

Comment: And why keep the for-loop?

Answer (score -1):

When you use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) result array have same element count as source.
What you want is just filter array, so use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Also if your source array sorter, so operator just show relation with index of selected element.

So your code should be like this

```
var selection = "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz";
var indexSelected = arr.indexOf(selection)
string_array = arr.filter(function(el, index){
    return index < indexSelected;
});
```

```js
var arr = [
    "/a_3312368_392921_800MHz", 
    "/a_3312368_392853_900MHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578261_1GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578167_140GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578230_160GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578192_180GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_397393_183GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_582870_186GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578174_190GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578177_2GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578922_210GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578479_220GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578357_226GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578182_240GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578919_250GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578349_253GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578639_280GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_579178_3GHz"
];
var selection = "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz";
var indexSelected = arr.indexOf(selection);
var string_array = arr.filter(function(el,index){
  return index < indexSelected;
  });

document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(string_array,null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

As say @Toffy in comment - in your case, seems, you need simple [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var indexSelected = arr.indexOf(selection)
string_array = arr.slice(0,indexSelected);
```

```js
var arr = [
    "/a_3312368_392921_800MHz", 
    "/a_3312368_392853_900MHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578261_1GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578167_140GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578230_160GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578192_180GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_397393_183GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_582870_186GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578174_190GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578177_2GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578922_210GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578479_220GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578357_226GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578182_240GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578919_250GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578349_253GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_578639_280GHz", 
    "/a_3312368_579178_3GHz"
];
var selection = "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz";
var indexSelected = arr.indexOf(selection);
var string_array = arr.slice(0,indexSelected);

document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(string_array,null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

Sample if source array not sorted

```
var selection = "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz";
var selectedFreq = getFreq(selection);

function getFreq(s) {
    var parts = s.match(/(\d+)(MHz|GHz)$/);
    return parts[1]* (parts[2] == "GHz" ? 1000: 1);    
}
var string_array = arr.filter(function(el) {
    var elFreq = getFreq(el);
    return selectedFreq > elFreq;
});
```

```js
var arr = [
  "/a_3312368_392921_800MHz",
  "/a_3312368_392853_900MHz",
  "/a_3312368_578261_1GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578922_210GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578479_220GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578357_226GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578182_240GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578919_250GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578349_253GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578639_280GHz",
  "/a_3312368_579178_3GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578167_140GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578230_160GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578192_180GHz",
  "/a_3312368_397393_183GHz",
  "/a_3312368_582870_186GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578174_190GHz",
  "/a_3312368_578177_2GHz",
];
var selection = "/a_3312368_578189_120GHz";
var selectedFreq = getFreq(selection);

function getFreq(s) {
  var parts = s.match(/(\d+)(MHz|GHz)$/);
  return parts[1]* (parts[2] == "GHz" ? 1000: 1);    
}
var string_array = arr.filter(function(el) {
    var elFreq = getFreq(el);
    return selectedFreq > elFreq;
});

document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(string_array, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

Comment: it's not my downvote by why are you re-implementing array.slice() ?

Comment: OPs code is shorter, faster and - imo - more explainable.

Comment: @Touffy, because condition in filter can be more complicated

Comment: Downvotes are very harsh, Grundy's answer does work after all.

Comment: @Ben, so if you think that answer helps - you can upvote :-)

Comment: @Grundy , just wanted to see if you got your downvotes removed before I voted. Done it now. Bit lost why "some()" and "every()" are getting upvoted when they don't construct an array. He does want a new array(by default), doesn't he?

Comment: I suppose if you put the "array.push()" in the "array.some()" you're only looping through the array once. Where as your solution loops through the array to get the index(behind the scenes), then loops again to build the new array. Still stand by the fact it works. Downvotes should be reserved for non constructive answers, surely.

Comment: @Ben, index for selected get only once, so also just one loop over array, but in `some` and `every` case loop breake when condition, but it works only for case when source array is sorted before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92232/discussion-between-ben-and-grundy).

Comment: @dev-null, i think OP code **not** shorter, faster and explainable than _slice_ :-)

Comment: @Grundy shorter yes, faster - in terms of performance - no - not a single array method is faster then a for loop - more explainable is up for debate.

Comment: @dev-null, preformance also depends from browser and from place selected element: http://jsperf.com/some-vs-slice/2

Comment: @Ben—there is no reason that *indexOf* must use a loop. An implementation may build an index as members are added, or keep a searchable, sorted object that is easily searched, or… whatever. Looking at [*performance*](http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-for-loop-2015), Chrome seems to have made optimisations so *indexOf* is much faster than a loop. Other browsers haven't.